# How to create Angular 1.5 custom directive requiring uibTypeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typeahead

I am trying to create a custom directive in AngularJs which requires uibTypeahead, but can't get it working. I am using Angular 1.5 version with angular-ui-bootstrap version 0.14.3. Below is my sample code -

```
function typeaheadOpenOnFocus($log) {
  return {
    require: ['uibTypeahead', 'ngModel'],
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrls) {          
      element.bind('focus', function () {
        $log.log("in typeaheadOpenOnFocus: ", ctrls);
        // ctrls[0].getMatchesAsync(ctrls[1].$viewValue);
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
}
```

I was expecting ctrls[0] to be UibTypeaheadController, since ctrls[1] is correctly resolving to NgModelController. Basically, I want to use getMatchesAsync function of UibTypeaheadController in link function. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears `getMatchesAsync` method is a private function in the controller.

By looking at the source, https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js, you can see they only expose the `this.init = function(_modelCtrl, _ngModelOptions)` method. All other methods are internal to the controller.

I have a similar question where I wanted to call that method as well within a directive: [Open AngularUI Bootstrap Typeahead Matches Results via Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026831/open-angularui-bootstrap-typeahead-matches-results-via-controller/)