# Open AngularUI Bootstrap Typeahead Matches Results via Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

Is there anyway to trigger opening the match results on a typeahead input text box from the controller?

use case:

- user goes to https://example.com/search/searchText
- controller of page sets the input text to "searchText" (ng-model) on initialization
- trigger showing the typeahead results from the controller

I can only seem to get the typeahead results, obviously, while typing in the input text box.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work in a couple ways, but both require changes to ui-bootstrap. I suppose I could create a pull request but not sure if my particular use case is a common one.

1) Custom directive and calling `UibTypeaheadController.scheduleSearchWithTimeout` method on focus of input element.

Directive:

```
.directive("showSearchResultsOnFocus", function($stateParams) {
return {
    require: ['uibTypeahead', 'ngModel'],
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
        var typeaheadCtrl = ctrls[0];
        var modelCtrl = ctrls[1];

        element.bind('focus', function () {
            if (!$stateParams.search || !modelCtrl.$viewValue) return;
            typeaheadCtrl.exportScheduleSearchWithTimeout(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
        });
    }
}
```

Update to ui-bootstrap:

```
this.exportScheduleSearchWithTimeout = function(inputValue) {
  return scheduleSearchWithTimeout(inputValue);
};
```

*Bad:* Requires making the method public on controller. Only method available is the `init` method and scope is isolated. Not meant to call from outside controller.

2) Add new typeahead attribute to allow setting default value and show results on focus:

Update to ui-bootstrap:

```
var isAllowedDefaultOnFocus = originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadAllowDefaultOnFocus) !== false;
originalScope.$watch(attrs.typeaheadAllowedDefaultOnFocus, function (newVal) {
  isAllowedDefaultOnFocus = newVal !== false;
});

element.bind('focus', function (evt) {
  hasFocus = true;
  // this was line before: if (minLength === 0 && !modelCtrl.$viewValue) {
  if ((minLength === 0 && !modelCtrl.$viewValue) || isAllowedDefaultOnFocus) {
    $timeout(function() {
      getMatchesAsync(modelCtrl.$viewValue, evt);
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

*Bad:* Pull Request to ui-bootstrap but change perhaps not a common use feature. Submitted a PR here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/6353 Not sure if will be merged or not but using fork until then.

Any other suggestions?

**Versions**
Angular: 1.5.8, UIBS: 2.2.0, Bootstrap: 3.3.7